# Proof of Morrey's inequality in Haim Brezis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, sobolev-spaces

I'm afraid I don't quite understand one of the steps in the following proof, I will highlight the offending step in red. The result is Theorem 9.12 (Morrey) in Brezis, Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations. I will discuss this in the one dimensional case to keep the notation clean.

**Theorem:** For all $u \in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$, we have

$$
|u(x)-u(y)| \leq C|x-y|^\alpha \|u'\|_{L^2} \quad a.e\quad  x,y \in \mathbb{R},
$$
where $\alpha=1/2$.

**Proof**,

We first prove this result for $u \in C_c^1(\mathbb{R})$. Let $x \in (-\frac{r}{2},\frac{r}{2})$ for some $r >0$. We have,

$$
u(x)-u(0)=\int_0^t \frac{d}{dt}u(tx)dt,
$$
thus,
$$
|u(x)-u(0)|\leq \int_0^t|x|\cdot|u'(tx)|dt \leq \frac{r}{2}\int_0^t|u'(tx)|dt.
$$
Set,
$$
\bar{u}=\frac{1}{r}\int_{-r/2}^{r/2}u(s)ds.
$$
Integrating our above inequality over the interval $(-\frac{r}{2},\frac{r}{2})$, we see,
\begin{align}
|\bar{u}-u(0)| & \leq  \frac{r}{2r}\int_{-r/2}^{r/2}\int_0^t|u'(tx)|dtdx\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\int_{-r/2}^{r/2}|u'(tx)|dxdt\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\int_{-tr/2}^{tr/2}|u'(v)|t^{-1}dvdt,
\end{align}
Then applying Holder's inequality to the inner integral we get,
\begin{align}
\int_{-tr/2}^{tr/2}|u'(v)|t^{-1}dv  & \leq \left( \int_{-tr/2}^{tr/2}|u'(v)|^2dv\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{-tr/2}^{tr/2}t^{-2}dv\right)^{1/2}\\
& \leq \sqrt{\frac{r}{t}} \cdot\|u'\|_{L_2}.
\end{align}
Thus we have,
\begin{align}
|\bar{u}-u(0)| & \leq \frac{\|u'\|_{L_2}}{2}\int_0^t\sqrt{\frac{r}{t}}dt\\
& = \sqrt{r} \cdot\|u'\|_{L_2}.
\end{align}

$\color{red}{\text{By translation, this inequality remains true for all intervals $I$ of length $r$, thus we have,}}$
$$
|\bar{u}-u(x)|\leq \sqrt{r} \cdot\|u'\|_{L_2} \quad \forall x\in I.
$$
$\color{red}{\text{By adding these (and using the triangle inequality) we obtain}},$
$$
|u(x)-u(y)| \leq 2\sqrt{r} \cdot\|u'\|_{L_2} \quad \forall x,y \in I.
$$
The result follows by setting $r = 2|x-y|$ and using the fact that $C_c^1(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$.

What I belive is the definition of $\bar{u}$ should change depending on where you choose your interval $I$ to be centered, but in the argument above the author makes it seem that $\bar{u}$ does not change. If anyone could help me to understand the steps highlighted in red it would be very much appreciated.